# Error [Errno 2] when deploying flask app to AWS beanstalk

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I keep getting the following error when trying to deploy my Flask application to AWS beanstalk:

> Cloning git://https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-oauth.git to
>   /opt/python/run/venv/src/flask-oauth Error [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory: 'git': 'git' while executing command git clone -q
>   git://https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-oauth.git
>   /opt/python/run/venv/src/flask-oauth Cannot find command 'git'

My requirements looks like this:

```
awscli==1.15.81
awsebcli==3.14.4
botocore==1.10.80
cement==2.8.2
click==6.7
colorama==0.3.9
docutils==0.14
Flask==1.0.2
httplib2==0.11.3
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
jmespath==0.9.3
MarkupSafe==1.0
-e git://https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-oauth.git#egg=flask-oauth
pathspec==0.5.5
pyasn1==0.4.4
python-dateutil==2.7.3
PyYAML==3.13
rsa==3.4.2
s3transfer==0.1.13
semantic-version==2.5.0
six==1.11.0
tabulate==0.7.5
termcolor==1.1.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

In the config.yml I added the following:

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
```

How can I solve this and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem, it's actually really simple, stupid that I didn't think about it immediatly.

Anyway, I deleted the following from the requirements.txt:

> -e git://https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-oauth.git#egg=flask-oauth

Then in the virtual enviroinment or server where you create the necesarry files you have to install git. Then this did the job:

```
git clone https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-oauth.git
```

After that you need to run the following command:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

It will put the installed packages from github in to the file.

And that's it, you are ready to go.

Comment: Shot in the dark since it has been half a decade, but when you say `Then in the virtual environment or server where you create the necessary files you have to install git` where in bean stalk did you do this?

Answer (score 1):

fix for this is adding the following in a "filename.config" file under ".ebextensions" in your repo

```
  yum:
    git: []
```

Basically the issue is that you don't have git installed